# converting data from db to chartjs areachart dynamic data

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js, pie-chart

i have a question about populating a dynamic data from the chartjs AREA Chart, now i manage to query from my database about all my clinics with these query result :

```
SELECT
tbl_clinics.clinic_name,
COALESCE(COUNT(tbl_check_up.check_up_id),0) AS total_checked_up
FROM
tbl_clinics
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_queue ON tbl_clinics.clinic_id = tbl_queue.clinic_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_check_up ON tbl_queue.queue_id = tbl_check_up.queue_id
WHERE tbl_clinics.user_id = 102
GROUP BY tbl_clinics.clinic_name
```

[image]
now, here is my ajax function where i get that query and the response of it is a json data object :

```
function getpieclinic() {
    $.ajax({
       url: siteurl+"patients_report/piedataclinic",
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "JSON",
        success:function(response) {
            alert(response)
        }
    });
}
```

now my question is how do i convert or put it like the chartjs areachart data to be look like. The Area chartjs format is this code below:

```
// Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
    var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
    var PieData = [
      {
        value: 700,
        color: "#f56954",
        highlight: "#f56954",
        label: "Chrome"
      },
      {
        value: 500,
        color: "#00a65a",
        highlight: "#00a65a",
        label: "IE"
      },
      {
        value: 400,
        color: "#f39c12",
        highlight: "#f39c12",
        label: "FireFox"
      },
      {
        value: 600,
        color: "#00c0ef",
        highlight: "#00c0ef",
        label: "Safari"
      },
      {
        value: 300,
        color: "#3c8dbc",
        highlight: "#3c8dbc",
        label: "Opera"
      },
      {
        value: 100,
        color: "#d2d6de",
        highlight: "#d2d6de",
        label: "Navigator"
      }
    ];
    var pieOptions = {
      //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
      segmentShowStroke: true,
      //String - The colour of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
      //Number - The width of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
      //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
      percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
      //Number - Amount of animation steps
      animationSteps: 100,
      //String - Animation easing effect
      animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
      //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
      animateRotate: true,
      //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
      animateScale: false,
      //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
      responsive: true,
      // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      //String - A legend template
      legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
    };
    //Create pie or douhnut chart
    // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
    pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
```

Comment: I've used a javascript library called Underscore to prepare data for charts before. I believe Lodash is what you should be using these days.

Comment: can you help me converet that my data to a dynamic data for chartjs?

Comment: Go to http://underscorejs.org/ and browse the functions. I look at the examples and find what I need. I don't know what your data looks like after it comes back. But you need to prepare an array of json objects...

Comment: It will be easier for you if you return the 4 columns out from your SQL SP: value, color, highlight and label

Comment: @TDP can you give me example how to solve my problem using underscorejs.org

Comment: What does the data look like that you get in the 'response'?

Comment: [{"clinic_name":"Clinic 1","total_checked_up":"4"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 2","total_checked_up":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 3","total_checked_up":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 4","total_checked_up":"0"}] = JSON OBJECT

Comment: any answers pls